# how to create- excel export operation for SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have SharePoint list now I want to export data from it. I have data filed on the list I want to export data with date range. file should export in the excel format.

Comment: please read data =date

Comment: Please help me for the same.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to export this is to create a view for the given date range and then choose **Export to Excel** in the **List** ribbon:

[image: Export To Excel in List Ribbon]

You'll have a few prompts to ok but everything should open in Excel just fine.

Alternatively, you can pull this information directly from Excel using the **Data** > **Get Data** option:

[image: Get directly from Excel]

There is a different option for SharePoint Online. The above screenshot is also Excel 2016. In earlier versions of Excel you needed to use the PowerQuery plugin (free from Microsoft).